# AMSART: Adding three-lines note (header) in the upper margin of the first page

Tags: header-footer, amsart

I'd like to add a three-lines note in the upper margin of the *first* page of a document in `amsart`. How do I do it?

---

For reference, this is the basic structure of the document:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\headsep}{10mm}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{7mm}

\begin{document}
\title[Short Title]{Long Title}
\author[Surname]{Name Surname}
\address{University}
\email{email@email.com}
\author[Surname2]{Name2 Surname2}
\address{University2}
\email{email2@email.com}
\date{14/09/2015}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: If this is going to be an article to be submitted to a paper, this note will most likely rejected

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the concern. But this is going to be a document for personal use, not a submitted paper.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: what makes you say that?

Comment: @JPi: Editors of journals will often remove non-conforming additions

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: depends much on the discipline and the publisher.

Comment: @JPi: Yes, that's why I wrote `most likely` or `often`, not `always` ;-)

Comment: i'd add to what @ChristianHupfer has said that if this were submitted to the ams, even before the extra note would be "adjusted", the code for `\usepackage{geometry}` would be removed; it doesn't play well with ams document classes, which have their own way of setting margins and positioning the copy on the output surface.  (conventions required by the rip that creates plates for mounting on the press.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put a three line note in two different places: top right hand corner of page and of text area.  You can decide which one you want.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\headsep}{10mm}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{7mm}

\begin{document}
\title[Short Title]{Long Title}
\author[Surname]{Name Surname}
\address{University}
\email{email@email.com}
\author[Surname2]{Name2 Surname2}
\address{University2}
\email{email2@email.com}
\date{14/09/2015}

\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {\parbox{3in}{\flushright Her name was Lola\\She was a showgirl\\With yellow feathers in her hair}};
 \node[anchor=north east] at (current page text area.north east) {\parbox{3in}{\flushright Her name was Lola\\She was a showgirl\\With yellow feathers in her hair}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT:  (following request)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\headsep}{10mm}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{7mm}

\begin{document}
\title[Short Title]{Long Title}
\author[Surname]{Name Surname}
\address{University}
\email{email@email.com}
\author[Surname2]{Name2 Surname2}
\address{University2}
\email{email2@email.com}
\date{14/09/2015}

\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \node[anchor=south east] at (current page header area.north east) {\parbox{3in}{\flushright Her name was Lola\\She was a showgirl\\With yellow feathers in her hair}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to move the one in the top right corner a little bit to the left in order to put it "in the same column" as the one in the "text area"?

Comment: done; see edit.